# Class statements in python

Tags: python

This code keeps on returning an error...object.**init**() does not have any perimeters.

```
class Car(object):
  def __init__(self,make,colour):
       object.__init__(self,make,colour)
       self.make = Ford
       self.colour = Black
  def display(self):
       print("Make:", self.make)
       print("Colour:", self.colour)
#main program 
cObj1 = Car("Ford", "Black") 
cObj1.display()
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: what have i done wrong in the programme above?

Comment: Just as the error says: you're passing parameters to `object.__init__`, which doesn't want any.

Comment: i am sorry ,i am not understanding what you are saying

Comment: You should not be forwarding those arguments on to the `object` classes `__init__` method.

Comment: You don't need to call `object.__init__()` at all.

Comment: @Raj Why are you calling `object.__init__`?

Comment: object.__init__ needs no arguments. You didn't need to explicit write object.__init__.

Comment: it is used for inheritance is it not?...after removing the object.__init__() it is giving an error that Ford is not Defined ....that is why i added object.__init__()

Comment: It should be `self.make = make` and likewise `self.colour = colour`. The only reason you didnt see that error previously is that it failed before it got to those lines.

Comment: @Raj Calling the super constructor is sometimes needed when using inheritance. The Object constructor isn't necessary to call though.

Comment: @PaulRooney Thank You i now understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `object.__init__()`, but that method doesn't take any parameters:

```
object.__init__(self,make,colour)
```

Just remove that line, it is not needed at all. `object.__init__` doesn't do anything, not calling it doesn't do any harm.

Next, you are ignoring the arguments, and are instead using the names `Ford` and and `Black`; those names are not defined in your code so that'll give you a `NameError` exception. Use `make` and `colour` instead:

```
def __init__(self, make, colour):
    self.make = make
    self.colour = colour
```

Comment: After removing the line an error saying that "NameError: name 'Ford' is not defined "

Comment: @Raj: what did you think `= Ford` would do? Presumably you wanted to use `= name` instead?